# Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in D:\xampp\htdocs\ipack\insertstatus.php on line 14

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting an error while running this code:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean in D:\xampp\htdocs\ipack\insertstatus.php on line 9

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    include 'dbconnection.php';
    $jobno = "AFE/0001/2015";
    $jobseq = 0;
    //to get INTJOBNO
    $intjobno = "";
    $data = $dbh->query("select INTJOBNO from PRTJOBHD where JOBNO = :jobno and JOBSEQ = :jobseq");
    $data->bindParam(':jobno',$jobno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $data->bindParam(':jobseq',$jobseq,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $data->execute();
    foreach($data as $row) {
         $intjobno = $row['INTJOBNO'];
         echo $intjobno;      
    }
>
```

Comment: You don't prepare your statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this answer: [PDO's query vs execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700623/pdos-query-vs-execute). You cannot bind parameters to PDO query, you need to use prepare instead.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include 'dbconnection.php';
$jobno = "AFE/0001/2015";
$jobseq = 0;
//to get INTJOBNO
$intjobno = "";
$data = $dbh->prepare("select INTJOBNO from PRTJOBHD where JOBNO = :jobno and JOBSEQ = :jobseq");
$data->bindParam(':jobno',$jobno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$data->bindParam(':jobseq',$jobseq,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$data->execute();
foreach($data as $row) {
     $intjobno = $row['INTJOBNO'];
     echo $intjobno;      
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Its working for me

Answer (score 0):

> **PDO::query()** returns a PDOStatement object, or **FALSE** on failure.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

It means your query has failed for some reason.

In this case you are using the wrong function to do what you want to do.

---

You need to prepare your statement since you want to bind two parameters in your query.

Use `$dbh->prepare()` instead of `$dbh->query()`.

Comment: `date()` returns a string.... And how should that solve OP's error ?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on boolean` it means that `$db->query()` has failed.

Comment: Reason why I told him to use `PDO::errorInfo()`.

Comment: Fixed @Rizier123, better?

Comment: Thanks @GiamPy. Its working for me..