# Checking if a record exists with PHP and sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, authentication

I'm totally new to programming (normally I'm a sysadmin) but now I have to do a project where you can register and logon, with PHP and SQLite (there's no alternative).
I need to get a statement where I can do a query:

> is there a user with the name from `$_POST['username']`

with SQLite.
I just don't get it... I found some articles but none of them really helped me.

This is my code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mysqlitedb.db');

$sql_create_table_users = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name TEXT,
    user_password TEXT
    )';
$db->execute($sql_create_table_users);

$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql_checkuserexist = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql_checkuserexist);
$stmt->execute(array(':user_name'=>$username));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (count($result) > 0) {
    echo 'Exists';
} else {
    echo 'Does not exist';
}
```

But here I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::exec()

This error shows to the line where I have

> $stmt->execute(array(':user_name'=>$username));

Does anyone know why? My table is called "users" and has got 3 rows: user_id, user_name and user_password.

@Kostas: This is my current code you gave me (I'm only working with this code atm):

```
try {
//Make your connection handler to your database
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mysqlitedb.db');
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql_create_table_users = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name TEXT,
    user_password TEXT
    )';
$stmt->execute($sql_create_table_users);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :username";
//Prepared statements so no SQL Injection occurs
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
//Execute your query
$stmt->exec(array(':username'=>$_POST['username']));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if (count($result) > 0) {
    echo 'Exists';
} else {
    echo 'Does not exist';
}

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
die();
}
```

Comment: You need to make a database connection.

Comment: Change to: $db = new PDO('sqlite:mysqlitedb.db');

Comment: didn't change anything... there's still this error

Comment: Also for executing prepared statements use 'execute' function.

Comment: Check if sqlite extension is on the server.

Comment: phpinfo(); Search for PDO drivers

Comment: Also you have $db = new DBO not PDO. Fix this using the correct PDO and try again.

Comment: sqlite is okay with my server. insert and create table etc. did work, but this statement doesn't...

Comment: yes I just typed it in here wrongly, in my code it's correct.

Comment: Try my updated answer to see what is the exception error.

Comment: There's an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() 
On this line where there is $db->execute($sql_create_table_users);

Comment: Also change from: $db->execute($sql_create_table_users); TO $db->exec($sql_create_table_users); Exec is for direct sql queries and execute for prepared statements.

Comment: Oh, NOT $db->execute($sql_create_table_users); BUT $stmt->execute($sql_create_table_users);

Comment: You call a plain sql query with database handler but when you have to call a prepared statement you have to call it via $stmt that previously had created.

Comment: Oh man, there are 2 new errors now:
Notice: Undefined variable: stmt       AND      Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on null             both on the same line as the error before ($stmt->execute($sql_create_table_users);

Comment: Just copy & paste the EXACT code you currently use so I will be able to fix it.

Comment: Copy & paste the exact code of my updated answer.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Phew.. Consider marking my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Sure! Just one more question: I've added this code:

$sql_select_users = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$result = $db->query($sql_select_users);
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
 print $row['user_id'] . '<br />';
 print $row['user_name'] . '<br />';
 print $row['user_password'] . '<br />';
}

But there's a problem with the line where i do the while () : Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetchArray() 

Do you know why?

Comment: Yes, replace with the following: $stmt = $db->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

Comment: Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700623/pdos-query-vs-execute

Comment: Oh my god, it still doesn't work... I'm just feeling so dumb! My code for getting all user's now: $query = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$stmt = $db->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
 print $row['user_id'] . '<br />';
 print $row['user_name'] . '<br />';
 print $row['user_password'] . '<br />';
}

 - But what's wrong?

Comment: Replace while loop with this: foreach($result as $row) {
    print $row['user_id'] . '<br />';
    print $row['user_name'] . '<br />';
    print $row['user_password'] . '<br />';
}

Comment: Manual should be your best friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code. You can find additional info [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php).

```
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:mysqlitedb.db');
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $username = '';
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :username";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if (count($result) > 0) {
        echo 'Exists';
    } else {
        echo 'Does not exist';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there really no easier way to do it?

Comment: PDO and prepared statements is the best way as far as I know. It avoids SQL Injection and you will have code consistency.

Comment: I've done this code:

$username = $_POST['username'];

$sql_checkuserexist = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = "' .$username. '"';
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_checkuserexist);
   
    $stmt->exec(array(':user_name'=>$username));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if (count($result) > 0) {
        echo 'Exists';
    } else {
        echo 'Does not exist';
    }

my table is called "users" with 3 rows: user_id, user_name and user_password. I got this error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::exec() (this is where there is $stmt->exec(array ... 

Can you see my error?

Comment: First: Change to this: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :user_name'

Comment: Then change also to this: $stmt->execute(array(':user_name'=>$username));

Comment: The above should fix the errors.

Comment: Hm, doesn't work either...

Comment: Have you made the connection to the database? Where do you create variable $db?

Comment: you can see my code in the top! I've added all things you need, I guess