# How to bind ISO8601 TSQL DATETIME parameter with PDO?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, iso8601

It seems that PDO has a problem with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted timestamps.

I'm connecting from 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 running PHP 7.0.8 using the [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13 (Preview) for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50419)

Here's my simple table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dtest (
    "stamp" DATETIME
);
```

## Works:

```
$pdoDB = new PDO('odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;
  Server='.DATABASE_SERVER.';
  Database='.DATABASE_NAME,
  DATABASE_USERNAME,
  DATABASE_PASSWORD
);
$pdoDB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES ('2011-03-15T10:23:01')";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
$params = [];
$stmt->execute($params);
```

## Does not work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
$params = ['2011-03-15T10:23:01'];
$stmt->execute($params);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (SQLExecute[0] at /build/php7.0-lPMnpS/php7.0-7.0.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:260)

**This works** if I delete the `T` so `'2011-03-15T10:23:01'` becomes `'2011-03-15 10:23:01'`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
$params = ['2011-03-15 10:23:01'];
$stmt->execute($params);
```

But I'm writing a script that runs nightly on about 2 million records, so I'd *really* rather not bear the overhead of running millions of [`str_replace('T', ' ', $param)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

I've also tried using [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), but it gives the **same error**:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES (:tdate)";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
$date = '2011-03-15T10:23:01';
$stmt->bindParam(':tdate',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Is there anyway to bind and execute this parameter as is? I'm a little dubious of the error message because it appears to be coming from SQL Server as if PDO did its job fine, but that doesn't make sense since *it's able to handle the type conversion without parameterization*.

---

I've also tried SQL conversion:

## Works:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-03-15T10:23:02', 126))";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
$params = [];
$stmt->execute($params);
```

## Does not Work:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, ?, 126))";
$stmt = $pdoDB->prepare($sql);
$params = ['2011-03-15T10:23:02'];
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Comment: Hi, any luck with this?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus nope, but I've been off all weekend so I'm gonna take another stab at it today.

Comment: Good luck! Let me know how it goes

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Could you solve this? This doesn't happen only with dates, but all bound parameters.

Comment: @Frondor for this particular problem, I was importing safe (pre-sanitized) data, so I skipped the binding altogether. Not a solution for user-input, so no, I still haven't solved it. I just try to avoid Microsoft's poorly supported junk as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use SQL Server's built-in [`convert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function and specify the format (**126**) which you are giving it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-03-15T10:23:01', 126))";
```

The documentation mentions `:mmm` at the end of your string so you might need to manually add `:000` at the end of your date string for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the same error when trying `$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES (convert(?, 126))";` Also note that the unprepared statement works just fine without conversion. `$sql = "INSERT INTO dtest (stamp) VALUES ('2011-03-15T10:23:01')";` It's the binding process that causes an issue.

Comment: In fact, this causes an additional `Syntax error or access violation: 102  Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Whoops! Sorry about that, I should have read your question details more carefully. That's weird though. Have you considered using [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) with `PARAM_STR` instead and seeing if things get any better?

Comment: Nope, that gives the same error - I have updated my question with the attempt.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I'm all out of ideas, it's possible that the mssql driver simply has an unresolved bug :(

Comment: @JeffPuckettII You mention that this code is used in a nightly script. Is there any reason, besides feeling good about parameterization :-), to not trust the data being inserted and just ignore binding for that field?

Comment: You're right - I think that should be OK for this field, but I'm under policy restrictions and that won't pass code review. If performance limitations persist though, then I might pursue an exemption.

Comment: CONVERT requires a data type, I.e. convert(datetime, '2011-03-15T10:23:01', 126)

Comment: @LaughingVergil Oh WOW, that is silly of me. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Check out Laughing Vergil's comment above. I don't have time to update my answer so give it a shot!

Comment: @LaughingVergil thanks for the sytnax fix, but that still results in the original error. I have updated my question with the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

After half a day spent trying to resolve the same issue, I ended up dropping odbc and using dblib instead. I installed php7.0-sybase package, adapted the data source name of my PDO connection and resolved once for all.
Now every bind is working.

Comment: Technically speaking, this is not the answer to the specific question, but it is such a damn good workaround alternative that I'm extremely tempted to "accept" it. You're right, I've been loving the Sybase drivers so much that I haven't used ODBC in ages. But I know I'll have more projects in the future (e.g. DB2) that will need ODBC and hopefully someone can answer that particularly.