# MS SQL prepare execute PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm getting nowhere with MS Sql and some php queries.

```
function getBillet($idBillet) {

    $connection = getBdd();
    $sql = 'select BIL_ID as id, BIL_DATE as date,
      BIL_TITRE as titre, BIL_CONTENU as contenu from t_billet
       where BIL_ID=?';
    $billet = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $billet->execute(array($idBillet));

    if ($billet->rowCount() == 1)
        return $billet->fetch();
    else
        throw new Exception('Aucun billet ne correspond à l\'identifiant' . $idBillet . ' ');
}
```

This one is not working, i'm trying to fetch the row with the ID inserted on parameter.
The connection to the database works fine, but I can't get the query to work. Especially since all the information on google is about MySQL but very few about MS SQL.
This one works fine for example :

```
function getBillets() {
$connection = getBdd();
$sql = 'select BIL_ID as id, BIL_DATE as date,
      BIL_TITRE as titre, BIL_CONTENU as contenu from t_billet
       order by BIL_ID desc';
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$resultat = $result->fetchAll();

return $resultat;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _This one is not working_ How? Giving errors? Giving something you dont expect? Not giving you what you do expect?

Comment: What does _not working_ mean?  Does it return anything, throw an exception?

Comment: It doesn't show anything, not an error nor any result.

Comment: Have you tried simply testing IF the prepare and execute are returning false and if so outputting the database error

Comment: It might be useful to see how you connect to the database

Comment: Yea I just tried testing with IF and both prepare and execute returns true.
So the problem is not the query ? Can't find the problem :\

Comment: The first one is wanting a parameter, did you pass SQL the parameter via PHP?

Comment: What OS are you using? What driver are you using (ODBC, Sybase, etc)? What version of PHP? I feel your pain with a variety of MSSQL issues such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38255659/4233593) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39044034/4233593) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40116280/4233593).