# MYSQL compare date time not returning any results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to get matches played between 2 certain dates. 
In MySQL terminal, I hardcoded the following query and got the following rows returned (to check whether my query is correct)

QUERY

```
SELECT * 
FROM schedule 
WHERE gameDateTime BETWEEN '2020-02-21 00:00:00' 
                       AND '2020-02-25 15:15:00'
```

[image]

HOWEVER, when I run this simple query through PHP I get NO results

PHP CODE

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE `gameDateTime` BETWEEN '2020-02-21 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-25 15:15:00'";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $games = $stmnt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($games as $game){
        echo $game['homeTeam'];
        echo 'VS';
        echo $game['awayTeam'];
        echo '<hr />';

    }
```

**DEBUGGING**

- I DID a select(*) to ensure I can retrieve data from my DB
- gameDateTime IS a datetiime() column

Help appreciated

Comment: You haven't executed the query. $stmnt->execute() is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an `$stmnt->execute()`

Note that you can replace `->prepare` with `->query` if you wish to run the query immediately rather than preparing it first.

More info: [PDO's query vs execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700623/pdos-query-vs-execute)

Answer (score 0):

You have not executed the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE `gameDateTime` BETWEEN '2020-02-21 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-25 15:15:00'";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt = $stmnt->execute();
    $games = $stmnt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($games as $game){
        echo $game['homeTeam'];
        echo 'VS';
        echo $game['awayTeam'];
        echo '<hr />';

    }
```