# I am trying to update data through query using PHP but no change in data in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update company table through query using PHP but no change in DB.
MySQL DB.

```
$pncon->query("UPDATE `company` SET 
                              `name` = '" . $companyName . "',
                              `parent_ID` = '" . $companyParent . "',
                              `address` = '" . $address . "',
                              `phone` = '" . $phone . "',
                              `fax` = '" . $fax . "',
                              `email` = '" . $email . "',
                              `remarks` = '" . $remarks . "',
                              `type` = '" . $system . "',
                              `status` = '". $status ."'
                              WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "' ");
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Update you question and put the whole peace of code of PDO execution

Comment: You don't execute it + it is not the correct way to do it in terms of security

Comment: Check for mysql / php errors with whatever library you are using to access  mysql.

Comment: Maybe $id doesn't match any rows in your database. P.s. this code is a SQL injection and/or syntax error issue waiting to happen, please learn how to write your queries correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine,but incorrect data types, invalid id or variables or violating other constraints may be the issue.

It is good using PDO statements as it is more secure.

You can modify your code as,

```
$sql = "UPDATE `company` SET 
  `name` = '" . $companyName . "',
  `parent_ID` = '" . $companyParent . "',
  `address` = '" . $address . "',
  `phone` = '" . $phone . "',
  `fax` = '" . $fax . "',
  `email` = '" . $email . "',
  `remarks` = '" . $remarks . "',
  `type` = '" . $type . "',
  `status` = '" . $status . "'
  WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "' " ;

$stmt = $pncon->prepare($sql); //prepare statement
$stmt->execute(); //execute the query
```

You can find the difference between PDO query and execute [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700623/pdos-query-vs-execute).

Answer (score -1):

```
$pncon->query("UPDATE company SET 
  name = '$companyName',
  parent_ID = '$companyParent',
  address = '$address',
  phone = '$phone',
  fax = '$fax',
  email = '$email',
  remarks = '$remarks',
  type = '$system',
  status = '$status'
  WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.